# Datamapper dirty properties

Tags: ruby, datamapper

I'm sure I remember a way to get a list of the properties for a resource that are dirty, but I can't seem to find the method anywhere.

So is there some method for returning an array of dirty properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dirty_attributes
```

This should do the trick:

http://rubydoc.info/github/datamapper/dm-core/master/DataMapper/Resource#dirty_attributes-instance_method